# Finding nearby hospitals with Overpass API

Tags: java, android, api

I am making an Android app that shows hospitals in a circular area of 3km. I have an http request for Overpass API that works fine when used in browser. But for some reason doesn't work in my code.

```
package com.example.ilovemilfs;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.wifi.hotspot2.pps.HomeSp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    String link;
    SupportMapFragment suppMapFragment;
    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient client;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationManager LManager;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    String googlePlacesData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fetchLastLocation();

        LManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    private void fetchLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            CheckGps();
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                    suppMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
                    suppMapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You are here!");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }

    private void CheckGps() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest).setAlwaysShow(true);

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> locationSettingsResponseTask = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getApplicationContext()).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gps is already enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    if (e.getStatusCode() == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED) {
                        ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        try {
                            resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, 101);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    }
                    if (e.getStatusCode() == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Setting not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    fetchLastLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==101){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Denied GPS permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }



    public void ibLokacija(View view){
        CheckGps();
    }

    public void ibRefreshRef(View view){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void ibHospital(View view){
        NearbyHospitals(currentLocation);
    }

    public void NearbyHospitals(Location l){
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    String uri = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][timeout:25];(node%5B%22amenity%22%3D%22hospital%22%5D(around%3A3000%2C%20" + String.valueOf(l.getLatitude()) + "%2C%20" + String.valueOf(l.getLongitude())
                            + ")%3Bway%5B%22amenity%22%3D%22hospital%22%5D(around%3A3000%2C%20" + String.valueOf(l.getLatitude()) + "%2C%20" + String.valueOf(l.getLongitude())
                            + ")%3Brelation%5B%22amenity%22%3D%22hospital%22%5D(around%3A3000%2C%20" + String.valueOf(l.getLatitude()) + "%2C%20" + String.valueOf(l.getLongitude()) + ");)%3Bout%20body;";

                    URL url = new URL(uri);

                    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) huc.getContent();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, stringBuilder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Hospitals(stringBuilder.toString());
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println(jsonObject);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void Hospitals(String s) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject locationJSON = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("elements").getJSONObject("tags");
                JSONObject nameJSON = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("elements").getJSONObject("tags");

                String street = locationJSON.getString("addr:street");
                String address = locationJSON.getString("addr:housenumber");
                String name = nameJSON.getString("name");

                LatLng latLng = getLocationFromAddress(this, street + address);

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.title(name);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String strAddress){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
        List<Address> addresses;
        LatLng p1 = null;

        try{
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 10);
            if(addresses == null){
                return null;
            }
            Address location = addresses.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return p1;
    }

}
```

This is the whole code for my app.

The `getLocationFromAddress` is a method that returns `lat` and `lon` from the json file, since from a couple of tests not every time I got lat and lon in the JSON.

The buttons are for testing functions, they won't be there after the code is finished.

I have tried switching `NearbyHospitals` from `public void` to `public string` and returning a string, but it didn't work.

This is the result from the http request, with manually entered coordinates(lat, lon):

```
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.60.2 e4cf9f7a",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2023-05-09T21:41:23Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 8365827932,
  "lat": 44.8719332,
  "lon": 20.6440964,
  "tags": {
    "amenity": "hospital",
    "healthcare": "hospital",
    "name": "Хитна помоћ",
    "name:sr": "Хитна помоћ",
    "name:sr-Latn": "Hitna pomoć"
  }
},
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 549923685,
  "nodes": [
    4991849837,
    4991849838,
    5312096854,
    5312096853,
    5312096852,
    5312096851,
    5312096850,
    7029526213,
    5312096849,
    4991849837
  ],
  "tags": {
    "addr:country": "RS",
    "addr:housenumber": "11",
    "addr:postcode": "26101",
    "addr:street": "Miloša Trebinjca",
    "amenity": "hospital",
    "email": "opstabolnica@bolnicapancevo.rs",
    "healthcare": "hospital",
    "name": "Opšta bolnica Pančevo",
    "name:sr": "Општа болница Панчево",
    "name:sr-Latn": "Opšta bolnica Pančevo",
    "operator:type": "government",
    "phone": "013306400",
    "website": "https://www.bolnicapancevo.rs/index.html",
    "wheelchair": "yes"
  }
}

  ]
}
```

UPDATE: I have managed to narrow it down to a singleproblem. When the method is called, in the Logcat I get this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: No value for elements`. Which, to me, makes no sense, since the `jsonArray` counts 2 hospitals from the JSON file, but in the logs it says there are no values.
This is the new `Hospitals` method:

```
private void Hospitals(String s) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("elements");
            Integer integer = jsonArray.length();
            String s1 = integer.toString();
            Log.i("ayo wtf 1", s1);
            for(int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject locationJSON1 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("tags");
                JSONObject locationJSON2 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("elements");
                String name = locationJSON1.getString("name");

                String lat_street = locationJSON2.getString("lat");
                String lon_housenumber = locationJSON2.getString("lon");
                LatLng latLng = null;

                if(lat_street != null && lon_housenumber  != null){
                    latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat_street), Double.parseDouble(lon_housenumber));
                }
                else {
                    lat_street = locationJSON1.getString("addr:street");
                    lon_housenumber = locationJSON1.getString("addr:housenumber");
                    latLng = getLocationFromAddress(MainActivity.this, lat_street + lon_housenumber);
                }

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.title(name);
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```